# How to print the Model.create calls made by FactoryGirl.create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, factory-bot

Is there any way to print the ActiveRecord operations called by FactoryGirl.create?

Say we have a factory `:foo` of model `Foo`. Running `FactoryGirl.create(:foo)`, creates a database entry for the model `Foo` and some other entries for different models, say `Bar`, `Car`, etc.

Is there any way in which we could convert this `FactoryGirl.create(:foo)` command into its underlying `Model.create` commands?

For example

```
FactoryGirl.create(:foo)
```

should break into

```
Foo.create(name: 'some name', ...)
Bar.create(field_value: 'asdf', ....)
Car.create(field_value: 'asdf1231', ....)
...
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the underlying operations? Print them? Run them separately? Something else?

Comment: I want to print these commands

Comment: If this is for debugging, why not just look at the generated SQL in log/test.log?

Comment: No. I want to generate all the database record using ActiveRecord ORM. But writing all those operations are time-consuming. I have already written all those operations in FactoryGirl. So wanted to convert it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

factory_girl calls `save!` when it creates a model, so you can get at least part way there by overriding `save!` in each of your models. Put this in `config/initializers/print_model_save.rb`:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_method :original_save!, :save!

  def save!
    puts "#{self.class.name}.create! #{attributes.symbolize_keys.inspect}"
    original_save!
  end

end
```

That will work for simple attributes. Complex attributes might require more complicated argument printing. Try it and see.

Comment: This approach works if I try and run `Foo.create()`. But it does not work with  `FactoryGirl.create(:foo)`

Comment: Awesome. Excellent Solution.